# Couldn't find Schedule with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ScheduleController#show Couldn't find Schedule with 'id'=swarm`

The error triggers when I click one of my routes and I figure this is due to Active Record looking for `id=swarm` and not finding it because it doesn't exist.

My methods / routes `swarm` (etc...) find the by `id` and load without issue until I implement the `show` method to show individual items.

My goal was to handle all of this with just one controller, but I am unsure if this is an issue with my routing or my controller.

schedule_controller.rb

```
class ScheduleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @schedules = Schedule.all
  end

  def show
    @schedules = Schedule.find(params[:id])
  end

  def swarm
    @swarm = Schedule.find([3, 4, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29, 30, 35, 36, 39, 40])
  end

  def reddevils
    @reddevils = Schedule.find([1, 2, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 23, 24, 21, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38])
  end

  def thunder
    @thunder = Schedule.find([5, 6, 9, 10, 15, 16, 19, 20, 21, 22, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33, 34])
  end

  def stampede
    @stampede = Schedule.find([1, 2, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 26, 29, 30, 37, 38])
  end

  def admirals
    @admirals = Schedule.find([3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 17, 18, 23, 24, 25, 26, 33, 34, 39, 40])
  end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # get 'schedule/index'

  resources :schedule

  root 'schedule#index'

# Schedule routes
  get 'schedule/swarm'
  get 'schedule/reddevils'
  get 'schedule/thunder'
  get 'schedule/stampede'
  get 'schedule/admirals'

end
```

EDIT: Posting views as requested:

views/schedule/index.html.erb

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="well team-list">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
      <li><%= link_to 'All Games', root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Botany Swarm', schedule_swarm_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Canterbury Red Devils', schedule_reddevils_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Dunedin Thunder', schedule_thunder_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Skycity Stampede', schedule_stampede_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'West Auckland Admirals', schedule_admirals_path %></li>
    </ul>
    <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="panel-title">
              <h4 class="text-center"><%= schedule.leagueGame %> - <%= schedule.home %> v <%= schedule.away %></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <span class="pull-left"><img src="<%= schedule.homeLogo %>" alt="<%= schedule.homeLogo %>"></span>
              <span class="text-center">Details of upcoming game <%= link_to 'Game Deets', schedule_path(schedule) %></span>
              <span><img class="pull-right" src="<%= schedule.awayLogo %>" alt="<%= schedule.awayLogo %>"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
              <span class="pull-left"><%= schedule.venue %></span>
              <span class="text-center">Tickets</span>
              <span class="pull-right"><%= schedule.date %></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: id value should not be `swarm` it should be an integer refers to the record id. Could you please post your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the ordering of routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  resources :schedule
  root 'schedule#index'
  get 'schedule/swarm'
  get 'schedule/reddevils'
  get 'schedule/thunder'
  get 'schedule/stampede'
  get 'schedule/admirals'
end
```

The route `schedule/swarm` is being matched with `schedule/:id`  generated by `resources :schedule` and it is being redirected to `schedule#show` with `id = swarm`

Solution:

Move the resources routes for schedule below the other routes. Changing this will work

> Note: One more thing move the `root` at the end of route file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  get 'schedule/swarm'
  get 'schedule/reddevils'
  get 'schedule/thunder'
  get 'schedule/stampede'
  get 'schedule/admirals'

  resources :schedule
  root 'schedule#index'
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Deepak-Mahakale this solved the issue.

Out of curiosity, as ExperimentsWithCode pointed out this may not be RESTful routing. So if there is a better simple solution for what I doing I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

`id` value should not be `swarm`. It should be an integer which is referring to your record id.

Assuming that you are triggering that request in view, it should be link this:

```
<%= link_to "Show", schedules_path(schedule) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are linking to your_url.whatever/schedule/swarm/id, where id is equal to a valid id of a row in your table.

You may need to define the wildcard 'id' in your route.

```
get 'schedule/swarm/:id'
```

One way to check if param[:id] exists is by adding a debugger into your code. You can require `byebug` in your gem file. Then add `debugger` as the first line in your show method. If you are running locally and have `rails s` running in terminal, this should pause and let you interact with your code at that point. Enter param[:id] to see what that param is and if id exists. If it does not exist, try adding it as mentioned above.

I know that :id is automatically placed in restful routes, but you do not appear to be doing restful routing.